# elf intel 32 output does not print

Tags: assembly, output, system-calls, elf

Hello I'm very new to assembly and I'm currently trying to make my own calculator. I figured out how to make the operations and it seems to work but I have some problems with the "resultat" part of the code.

Depending on what operation I choose to make the output isn't the same and I don't really understand why.

If I choose to make an addition it will output the result but not the phrase I want before "le resultat est : " If I choose square root(sqrt) it just wont output anything.

I tried to debug it but I'm really bad at it and I didn't understood why it would not work. I don't really know what part of the code is making this mess so I'll link the entire code sorry.

I'm really curious to understand why it does not work and if you have general tips to make my code better I'm glad to read them too.

```
SYS_WRITE equ 4
SYS_READ equ 3
SYS_EXIT equ 1
STDIN equ 0
STDOUT equ 1

section .data
msgchoix dw 'Bonjour veulliez choisir le type de calcul en rentrant 1:addition 2:mul 3:div 4:sqrt 5:log',0xa
lenmsgchoix equ $ - msgchoix
msg1add dw 'Bonjour veuillez choisir un nombre a additionner',0xa
lenmsg1add equ $ - msg1add
msg2add dw 'le deuxieme',0xa
lenmsg2add equ $ - msg2add
msg1mul dw 'premier nombre a multiplier',0xa
lenmsg1mul equ $ - msg1mul
msg2mul dw 'deuxieme nombre',0xa
lenmsg2mul equ $ - msg2mul
msg1div dw "le nombre a diviser",0xa
lenmsg1div equ $ - msg1div
msg2div dw "le diviseur",0xa
lenmsg2div equ $ - msg2div
msg1sqrt dw "le nombre dont vous voulez la racine",0xa
lenmsg1sqrt equ  - msg1sqrt
msg3 dw 'le resultat est : '
lenmsg3 equ $ - msg3
msg4 dw '',0xa

section .bss
choix resb 2
num1 resb 2
num2 resb 2
mid1 resb 2
sum resb 2

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov eax,SYS_WRITE
    mov ebx,STDOUT
    mov ecx,msgchoix
    mov edx,lenmsgchoix
    int 0x80

    ;choix du type de calcul

    mov eax,SYS_READ
    mov ebx,STDIN
    mov ecx,choix
    mov edx,2
    int 0x80

    mov ecx,[choix]
    cmp ecx,0x00000a31
    je addition
    cmp ecx,0x00000a32
    je multiplication
    cmp ecx,0x00000a33
    je division
    cmp ecx,0x00000a34
    je sqrt

sqrt :
    mov eax,SYS_WRITE
    mov ebx,STDOUT
    mov ecx,msg1sqrt
    mov edx,lenmsg1sqrt
    int 0x80

    mov eax,SYS_READ
    mov ebx,STDIN
    mov ecx,num1
    mov edx,1
    int 0x80

    mov edx,[num1]

    jmp sqrtcalc

sqrtcalc :

    mov eax,[sum]
    sub eax,'0'
    mov ecx,[num1]
    div ecx
    add ecx,'0'

    add ecx,[sum]

    mov eax,2
    sub eax,'0'
    sub ecx,'0'
    div ecx
    add ecx,'0'

    cmp [sum],ecx
    mov [sum],ecx
    je resultat
    jne sqrtcalc

division :

    mov eax,SYS_WRITE
    mov ebx,STDOUT
    mov ecx,msg1div
    mov edx,lenmsg1div
    int 0x80

    mov eax,SYS_READ
    mov ebx,STDIN
    mov ecx,num1
    mov edx,2
    int 0x80

    mov eax,SYS_WRITE
    mov ebx,STDOUT
    mov ecx,msg2div
    mov edx,lenmsg2div
    int 0x80

    mov eax,SYS_READ
    mov ebx,STDIN
    mov ecx,num2
    mov edx,2
    int 0x80

    ;calcul

    mov ebx,[num1]
    sub ebx,'0'

    mov eax,[num2]
    sub ebx,'0'

    div ebx
    add ebx,'0'
    mov [sum],ebx

    jmp resultat

multiplication:

    mov eax,SYS_WRITE
    mov ebx,STDOUT
    mov ecx,msg1mul
    mov edx,lenmsg1mul
    int 0x80

    mov eax,SYS_READ
    mov ebx,STDIN
    mov ecx,num1
    mov edx,2
    int 0x80

    mov eax,SYS_WRITE
    mov ebx,STDOUT
    mov ecx,msg2mul
    mov edx,lenmsg2mul
    int 0x80

    mov eax,SYS_READ
    mov ebx,STDIN
    mov ecx,num2
    mov edx,2
    int 0x80

    ;calcul

    mov eax,[num1]
    sub eax,'0'

    mov ebx,[num2]
    sub ebx,'0'

    mul ebx
    add eax,'0'
    mov [sum],eax

    jmp resultat

addition :

    mov eax,SYS_WRITE
    mov ebx,STDOUT
    mov ecx,msg1add
    mov edx,lenmsg1add
    int 0x80

    mov eax,SYS_READ
    mov ebx,STDIN
    mov ecx,num1
    mov edx,2
    int 0x80

    mov eax,SYS_WRITE
    mov ebx,STDOUT
    mov ecx,msg2add
    mov edx,lenmsg2add
    int 0x80

    mov eax,SYS_READ
    mov ebx,STDIN
    mov ecx,num2
    mov edx,2
    int 0x80

    ;calcul

    mov eax,[num1]
    sub eax,'0'

    mov ebx,[num2]
    sub eax,'0'

    add eax,ebx
    add eax,'0'
    mov [sum],eax

    jmp resultat

resultat:

    mov eax,SYS_WRITE
    mov ebx,STDOUT
    mov ecx,msg3
    mov ebx,lenmsg3
    int 0x80

    mov eax,SYS_WRITE
    mov ebx,STDOUT
    mov ecx,sum
    mov edx,2
    int 0x80

    mov eax,SYS_WRITE
    mov ebx,STDOUT
    mov ecx,msg4
    mov edx,1
    int 0x80

    jmp exit

exit:
    mov eax,SYS_EXIT
    xor ebx,ebx
    int 0x80
```

Comment: Why are your strings declared with `dw`? ASCII characters are 1 byte each, not 1 word.

Comment: `cmp ecx,0x00000a31` is a pretty tedious way of doing things. Just write `cmp cl,'1'`. Also, things like `jmp exit` are pointless if `exit:` is the very next line of code, with no instructions or data in-between.

Comment: You're also doing 4-byte read and writes from/to variables that you've declared with `resb 2`. And you seem to ignore that the dividend for `div r/m32` is `edx:eax` (i.e. that you need to clear `edx` prior to the division to avoid an overflow).

Comment: Looks like it was just a typo in a register name.  `strace ./a.out` is a great debugging tool for that: tracing system calls and decoding the args will catch cases where you didn't actually have the right value in an arg-passing register.

Answer (score 1):

> I didn't understood why it would not work

```
mov eax,SYS_WRITE
mov ebx,STDOUT
mov ecx,msg3
mov ebx,lenmsg3    # <<<--- overwrites EBX, EDX intended
int 0x80
```

Comment: thanks fixed this little mistake and recompiled it but it still does not work. It now print the message I want (le resultat est:) but does not print the result. Any other ideas I can try ?

Comment: @Pancake You should fix all the other issues identified in the comments, and if it _still_ doesn't work, ask a new question with updated source.